# Action Mailer in Ruby on Rails framework does not send emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I started studying Ruby on Rails.
To be familiar with Action Mailer I followed the guide on https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html.

What I did were

First, created the UserMailer in the Ubuntu Terminal.

```
$ rails generate mailer User
```

Second, updated the *app/mailers/application_mailer.rb* file.

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "incrediblehealer0726@gmail.com"
  layout 'mailer'
end
```

Third, updated the *app/mailers/user_mailer.rb* file.

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def welcome_email
    @user = params[:user]
    @url  = 'http://example.com/login'
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Welcome to My Awesome Site')
  end
end
```

Next, created the *app/views/user_mailer/welcome_email.html.erb* file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome to example.com, <%= @user.name %></h1>
    <p>
      You have successfully signed up to example.com,
      your username is: <%= @user.login %>.<br>
    </p>
    <p>
      To login to the site, just follow this link: <%= @url %>.
    </p>
    <p>Thanks for joining and have a great day!</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Next, created the *app/views/user_mailer/welcome_email.text.erb* file.

```
Welcome to example.com, <%= @user.name %>
===============================================

You have successfully signed up to example.com,
your username is: <%= @user.login %>.

To login to the site, just follow this link: <%= @url %>.

Thanks for joining and have a great day!
```

Then, created User scaffold and migrated.

```
$ rails generate scaffold user name email login
$ rails db:migrate
```

Last, added mail sending line in the *app/controllers/users_controller.rb* file.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  # ...

  # POST /users or /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        # Tell the UserMailer to send a welcome email after save
        UserMailer.with(user: @user).welcome_email.deliver_later

        format.html { redirect_to(@user, notice: 'User was successfully created.') }
        format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # ...
end
```

I tested code and tried to add a new user. The user is successfully added to the database, but the email was not sent.

**What else should I do to send a email at the user registeration?**

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration you have to include what server and port and so on you are using

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will try Action Mailer Configuration.

Comment: you can use mailsnag.com or similar service to test sending with sandboxed real SMTP server